# Correct way to load a Nib for a UIView subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I am aware this question has been asked before but the answers are contradicting and I am confused, so please don't flame me.

I want to have a reusable `UIView` subclass throughout my app. I want to describe the interface using a nib file.

Now let's say it's a loading indicator view with an activity indicator in it. I would like on some event to instantiate this view and animate in to a view controller's view. I could describe the view's interface no problem programmatically, creating the elements programmatically and setting their frame inside an init method etc.

How can I do this using a nib though? Maintaining the size given in interface builder without having to set a frame.

I've managed to do it like this, but I'm sure it is wrong (it's just a view with a picker in it):

```
 - (id)initWithDataSource:(NSDictionary *)dataSource {
        self = [super init];
        if (self){
            self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self class]] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            self.pickerViewData = dataSource;
            [self configurePickerView];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

But I'm overwriting self, and when I instantiate it:

```
FSASelectView *selectView = [[FSASelectView alloc] initWithDataSource:selectViewDictionary];
    selectView.delegate = self;

    selectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bottom + 50, [FSASelectView width], [FSASelectView height]);
```

I have to manually set the frame rather than have it picked up from IB.

EDIT: I want to create this custom view in a view controller, and have access to control the view's elements. I don't want a new view controller.

Thanks

**EDIT: I Don't know if this is best practice, I'm sure it's not, but this is how I did it:**

```
FSASelectView *selectView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[FSASelectView class]] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    selectView.delegate = self;
    [selectView configurePickerViewWithData:ds];
    selectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bottom + 50, selectView.width, selectView.height);
    selectView.alpha = 0.9;
    [self.view addSubview:selectView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.25 delay: 0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                            selectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bottom - selectView.height, selectView.width, selectView.height);
                            selectView.alpha = 1;
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        }];
```

**Correct practice still wanted**

Should this have been done using a view controller and init with nib name? Should I have set the nib in some UIView initialisation method in the code? Or is what I have done ok?

Comment: But isn't the first line of code almost the same as  the one you used in the original question in `initWithDataSource`? Anyway this will work even if you give owner as 'Nil'.

Comment: It's worth noting that these days in 99.99999% of cases, one would just be using **container views**, which are now used everywhere and always in iOS.  [how-to article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884)

Comment: side note that you can replace [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[FSASelectView class]] with NSStringFromClass([FSASelectView class])

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
MyViewClass *myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewClassNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```

I'm using this to initialise the reusable custom views I have.

---

Note that you can use **"firstObject"** at the end there, it's a little cleaner. "firstObject" is a handy method for NSArray and NSMutableArray.

Here's a typical example, of loading a xib to use as a table header. In your file YourClass.m

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TopArea" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
}
```

Normally, in the `TopArea.xib`, you would click on File Owner and **set the file owner to YourClass**. Then actually **in YourClass.h** you would have IBOutlet properties. In `TopArea.xib`, you can drag controls to those outlets.

Don't forget that in `TopArea.xib`, you may have to **click on the View itself** and drag that to some outlet, so you have control of it, if necessary. (A very worthwhile tip is that when you are doing this for table cell rows, you absolutely have to do that - you have to connect the view itself to the relevant property in your code.)

Comment: there's no initWithNibName: method for a UIView, it's just for UIViewController

Comment: That's for a view controller, I want to use a UIView and have the controller that creates it to own it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied the wrong code in my haste, I've updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct. I don't know if it's best practice but it works.

Comment: @Joe Blow Sorry for the bump, but why would one have to do this: "Don't forget that in TopArea.xib, you may have to click on the View itself and drag that to some outlet, so you have control of it, if necessary." Could you instead just use myViewObject to access the underlying view as it is a UIView itself? Why is there a need for a property?

Comment: Umm .. I don't know  :)  I forget .. nobody has used nib views for years. Go to container views!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884  As you suggest it could be I confused view controllers with views, while writing there.  Thanks for the point...

Comment: I did the same, seems fine, but when I instantiate the instance variables in this method they are becoming nil. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 39):

If you want to keep your `CustomView` and its `xib` independent of `File's Owner`, then follow these steps

- Leave the `File's Owner` field empty.
- Click on actual view in `xib` file of your `CustomView` and set its `Custom Class` as `CustomView` (name of your custom view class)
- Add `IBOutlet` in `.h` file of your custom view.
- In `.xib` file of your custom view, click on view and go in `Connection Inspector`. Here you will all your IBOutlets which you define in `.h` file
- Connect them with their respective view.

in `.m` file of your `CustomView` class, override the `init` method as follow

```
-(CustomView *) init{
    CustomView *result = nil;
    NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options: nil];
    for (id anObject in elements)
    {
        if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        {
            result = anObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now when you want to load your `CustomView`, use the following line of code
`[[CustomView alloc] init];`

Comment: As of iOS 9, this is the only solution listed on this page which actually works for me (the other solutions cause crashing).

Comment: Just note that this approach is not compatible with loading your custom view from an existing XIB since it does not call `-init`. Instead it will call `initWithFrame:` and `-awakeFromNib`. If you write the same code to load your view as in the `-init` method you will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 25):

Follow the following steps

1. Create a class named MyView .h/.m of type `UIView`.
2. Create a xib of same name `MyView.xib`.
3. Now change the File Owner class to `UIViewController` from `NSObject` in xib. See the image below
   [image]
4. Connect the File Owner View to your View. See the image below
   [image]
5. Change the class of your View to `MyView`. Same as 3.
6. Place controls create IBOutlets.

Here is the code to load the View:

```
UIViewController *controller=[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
MyView* view=(MyView*)controller.view;
[self.view addSubview:myview];
```

Hope it helps.

**Clarification**:

`UIViewController` is used to load your xib and the View which the `UIViewController` has is actually `MyView` which you have assigned in the MyView xib..

**Demo**
I have made a demo grab [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78701794/TestApp.zip)

Comment: Why are people down voting this, wrong? I've not tried yet, but this looks like it wont do what I want.

Comment: I had down-voted, but thats cause I mis-read your answer (thought you were assigning a UIView subclass as the file's owner). Sorry about that.

Comment: In your xib file ignore the files owner. Then you can avoid having to create a UIViewController by just doing a MyView *view = [[UINib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: @LightningStryk Yes of course, but it just another way to do it.

Comment: The is to create a reusable UIView subclass, not to use a UIViewController for that purpose.

Comment: @arielyz See the answer properly, its an other way to do it.. By the way I am not using UIViewController but accessing the view attached to it.

Answer (score 11):

Answering my own question about 2 or something years later here but...

It uses a protocol extension so you can do it without any extra code for all classes.

```
/*

Prerequisites
-------------
- In IB set the view's class to the type hook up any IBOutlets
- In IB ensure the file's owner is blank

*/

public protocol CreatedFromNib {
    static func createFromNib() -> Self?
    static func nibName() -> String?
}

extension UIView: CreatedFromNib { }

public extension CreatedFromNib where Self: UIView {

    public static func createFromNib() -> Self? {
        guard let nibName = nibName() else { return nil }
        guard let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil).last as? Self else { return nil }
        return view
    }

    public static func nibName() -> String? {
        guard let n = NSStringFromClass(Self.self).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last else { return nil }
        return n
    }
}

// Usage:
let myView = MyView().createFromNib()
```

Answer (score 8):

In Swift:

For example, name of your custom class is `InfoView`

At first, you create files `InfoView.xib` and `InfoView.swift`like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InfoView: UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "InfoView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

Then set `File's Owner` to `UIViewController` like this:

[image]

Rename your `View` to `InfoView`:

[image]

Right-click to `File's Owner` and connect your `view` field with your `InfoView`:

[image]

Make sure that class name is `InfoView`:

[image]

And after this you can add the action to button in your custom class without any problem:

[image]

And usage of this custom class in your `MainViewController`:

```
func someMethod() {
    var v = InfoView.instanceFromNib()
    v.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(v)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could either initialize the xib using a view controller and use viewController.view. or do it the way you did it. Only making a `UIView` subclass as the controller for `UIView` is a bad idea.

If you don't have any outlets from your custom view then you can directly use a `UIViewController` class to initialize it.

**Update:** In your case:

```
UIViewController *genericViewCon = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView"];
//Assuming you have a reference for the activity indicator in your custom view class
CustomView *myView = (CustomView *)genericViewCon.view;
[parentView addSubview:myView];
//And when necessary
[myView.activityIndicator startAnimating]; //or stop
```

Otherwise you have to make a custom `UIViewController`(to make it as the file's owner so that the outlets are properly wired up).

```
YourCustomController *yCustCon = [[YourCustomController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourXibName"].
```

Wherever you want to add the view you can use.

```
[parentView addSubview:yCustCon.view];
```

However passing the another view controller(already being used for another view) as the owner while loading the xib is not a good idea as the view property of the controller will be changed and when you want to access the original view, you won't have a reference to it.

**EDIT:** You will face this problem if you have setup your new xib with file's owner as the same main `UIViewController` class and tied the view property to the new xib view.

i.e;

- YourMainViewController -- manages -- mainView
- CustomView -- needs to load from xib as and when required.

The below code will cause confusion later on, if you write it inside view did load of `YourMainViewController`. That is because `self.view` from this point on will refer to your customview

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(){
  UIView *childView= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Ok, so basically, best practice states that every UIView should have an associated controller?

Comment: Not necessarily. But when loading a view from a separate xib that would be the problem-free way. Pre-IOS5 apple docs says one view controller should not be used to control more than one scene (xib) and vice-versa.

Comment: The xib is actually only the size of an alert view

Comment: I personally feel, it depends on the complexity of code/xib whether you have to create a new controller or not. If you can handle the problems caused successfully and if you are not looking at future modifications it's not a problem. But creating a separate view controller would solve a lot of problems for you. And since in your case its just a activity indicator you can use a UIViewController(as mentioned in answer) object easily. I'll update my answer to do this accordingly.

Comment: Anyway if it's just a small view(logically and physically) you can put in the main view itself. Changing the class of your view to the custom class should take care of your problems, right?
What I am trying to say is: if it's not big enough to take care using another controller why separate it in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The view controller that was created is redundant. You are only making use of it's view property.

Comment: Redundant because you are not using the view controller at all. Yes. But then why separate it into a different xib? :)

Comment: So I can draw the interface in interface builder rather than doing it programmatically. It's not a problem doing it programmatically, I just want to know how to subclass a UIView and give it a nib! This shouldn't be hard.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26163/discussion-between-rakesh-and-adam-waite)