# Open a .xib from a class without the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, xib

Is it possible to load a `.xib` file without loading it via `self.view`?

I have tried the following:

```
UINib *customNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ViewControllerContact" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerContact *customView = [[customNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

However, because the current class the code is executing doesn't have a view (it is just an `NSObject`) it wont launch the `.xib`.

Comment: See answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405916/correct-way-to-load-a-nib-for-a-uiview-subclass). Note that your nib should contain only the view without a view controller. It is unclear from your description whether the nib contains a view controller.

Comment: A .xib file is just an archive of objects. What does "open a .xib" or "launch the .xib" mean?