# Objective-C self.delegate is null after being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I've setup a pretty simple delegate, for a UIView. However, when I try to do:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedPlayTrailer:)]){
    [self.delegate selectedPlayTrailer:self];
}
```

My self.delegate is null.  I checked the setter that the class being set as the delegate is right by:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<MyViewDelegate>)delegateClass
{
    // Whether I overwrite this method or not, it's still null.
    NSLog(@"%@", delegate);
    _delegate = delegateClass;
}
```

And it's correct. But by the time it's called in my IBAction - it's null.

EDIT: To clarify, I only dropped this in to see what was being passed in. If I don't overwrite this method, it's still null.

My code:

**MyView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyView;

@protocol MyViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void) myDelegateMethod:(MyView *)sender;
@end

@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyViewDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

**MyView.m**

```
@implementation MyView

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)init
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil];

    return self;
}

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    // NOTE: Here, self.delegate is null
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateMethod:)]){
        [self.delegate myDelegateMethod:self];
    }
}

@end
```

**MyCollectionViewCell.m**

```
#import "MyCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "MyView.h"

@interface MyCollectionViewCell() <MyViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyView *myView;
@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

@synthesize myView;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self){
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.myView = [MyView new];
    self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    self.myView.alpha = 0.0;
    self.myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.myView.delegate = self;

    [self addSubview:self.myView];
}

// The delegate method
- (void)myDelegateMethod:(MyView *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"This is never called...");
}

@end
```

Comment: Is it possible that the delegate has been released?  Try changing the delegate property from weak to assign and turn on zombies - see if you get an error.

Comment: initWithFrame is called ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Tried but no error and still null. Also tried setting it to strong (I know you usually shouldn't for delegate properties) but that didn't help either.

Comment: @Selvin Yep. The view is added correctly, no errors but then the delegate is nullified by the time I call the IBAction.

Comment: Try setting the ViewController as the delegate instead of collectioviewcell

Comment: Show us the code where you set `delegate`.  (I'm betting you're creating multiple instances of the class containing your delegate pointer.)

Comment: @HotLicks That's it there. Inside the setup method I'm setting self.myView.delegate = self; which is pointing to the MyCollectionViewCell.  I've just tried moving that out to the ViewController, as suggested by Selvin, but the same thing is happening. Setup is called once for each cell that is created.

Comment: And how many other places do you create a "MyView" object?

Comment: self.myView = [MyView new]; may be the problem. Try using stackoverflow.com/a/15406012/569497 to allocate the view

Comment: @HotLicks Just here, It's a specific view that belongs inside that cell, for only this ViewController. It should be pretty straight forward and I'm at a loss for ideas. Just doing what selvin has suggested changing [MyView new];

Comment: @Matt have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Selvin Yep. See comment on your answer below. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the viewcontroller as the delegate of MyView object instead of collection view cell.

In your view controller, inside the datasource method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

do something like this.

```
cell.myView.delegate = self;
```

**Update**

As observed, the problem is in allocating the `UIView` subclass. Initializing the view as

```
self.myView = [MyView new];
```

does not work for some reason. To properly allocate the view, the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406012/569497) can be used.

```
 self.myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibNamed:@"MyView"
        owner:self options:nil]
         firstObject];
```

Comment: Okay, tried it but getting the same thing. It's null. When I overwrite the setter it's saying <MyFeedViewController: 0x7f9783c16f90> is the one being set as the delegate.  But when I run the app and click the button to trigger the IBAction self.delegate is still (null)

Comment: `MyView` init method can be wrong. It could create 2 instances

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15406012/569497 use this approach to init your subclass

Comment: Thanks, I'll change that. I'm guessing when you initialize it that way initWithCoder is called?

Comment: This fixed it. 

Changing [MyView new] to loading the nib as suggested at that link fixed it. I'm not sure entirely why at the moment. init doesn't appear to be called anymore times than initWithCoder (with the other initializing method) but my method is definitely the culprit. I've been using [MyView new] for a while as a shortcut to alloc init - should I be staying away from this? Or at least when initializing a view with a nib? If you wouldn't mind updating your answer with your other suggestion, I'll accept it.  Thank you very much for your help Selvin.

Comment: For allocating custom UIView subclasses I have always used `[[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibNamed:@"nibname"
        owner:self options:nil]
         firstObject];` method. For `UIViewController` subclasses, [ViewController new] works. But not for `UIView` subclasses. Very strange indeed!

Answer (score 2):

To `MyCollectionViewCell` add this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"MyCollectionViewCell dealloc called")
}
```

`delegate` is a weak reference. So if the instance which is set to the `delegate` is released, it will become nil. The purpose of the above is to confirm this is happening.

Why would this happen? If nothing is maintaining a strong reference to the `MyCollectionViewCell` instance, then it will be released.

Ideally, you'd also want to add an `NSLog` to `myButtonPressed:`. It would also be beneficial if you `NSLog`'d the setting of the delegate. So your output could be potentially something like:

```
Delegate set
MyCollectionViewCell dealloc called <- this would indicate that the delegate becomes nil based on the instance being released
myButtonPressed: hit
```

This is a working theory, given the amount of info you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it but the collectionviewcell isn't being deallocated. The code that's setting up the cell isn't anything funky either. It's just the usual dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier