# Properly initializing & using custom XIB UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched around StackOverflow for the optimal way to initialize and use a custom XIB UIView when working with a Storyboard, and all I've found was solutions similar to this one:

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self.subviews.count == 0){
        SomeCustomView *viewFromNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeCustomView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;

        self.someProperty = viewFromNib.someProperty;

        [self addSubview:viewFromNib];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But technically speaking, this would be adding a subview to the existing view on the Storyboard.

How would I simply just utilize the contents of the UIView without having to add it as a subview?

Something like this:

`self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeCustomView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;`

But when I do that, it returns `BAD_EXEC` error.

Comment: Check 2nd answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405916/correct-way-to-load-a-nib-for-a-uiview-subclass)

Comment: Where it is showing BAD_EXEC?